# "Quel est la <>" ou "Quelle est la <>" ?

Tags: accord

Quand il est sujet, faut-il accorder "quel" ? Doit-on dire "Quelle est la solution" ou "Quel est la solution" ?

Merci

Comment: Il faut accorder : « Quelle est la solution ? »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il faut absolument accorder en genre et en nombre :

> - Quelle est la solution ?
> - Quelles sont les solutions ?